# Postman: how to fetch response data from one API and use it in another API (if I have two APIs in one collection)

Tags: postman, web-api-testing, postman-collection-runner

I have two API one is for login and the other provides details regarding the data.

My first API returns an authentication key that is required to get the details from the second API. The authentication key is different for all users.

I have kept both API's in a collection and run them. I want to get the authentication key from the first API and use it in the second API dynamically so that for any user I don't have to hard-code the authentication key and use it. I just have to read the CSV file and get the authentication key accordingly.

I have tried:

```
var contract = datas[y];
pm.globals.set('details', contract);
pm.globals.get(details)
let dat = pm.globals.get(details);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot reference object details

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `environment` or `global` variables to store the value from the first response, then use this value with the request header(?) of the second request.

I'm guessing the names and Auth mechanism here as you haven't provided the information in the question:

`pm.environment.set('token', pm.response.json().access_token)`

Adding something like that to the first request, in the test tab, will store the token.

You can then use the `{{access_token}}` syntax in the request header section as the Auth token.

This will make the action more dynamic and allow you to stop hardcoding values.

Comment: I have tried it. I wanted to check the value it holds by printing it in the console after second API by storing it in a variable,  but in that case it gave error-"Cant refference object".

Comment: You've provided no context or information about what you're trying. It might be better to update your original question first and then I/anyone else will be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: I can't see what you have updated, it still makes no sense and the code you added is meaningless on it's own. By 'APIs' do you mean endpoints? What does the response body, from the first request look like? How are you trying to use this data in the second request. Don't be afraid to add pictures/images of how you have this set up already - give people more details to understand the question and help with a solution.